# JQuery appendTo method overrides existing node in XML document

Tags: jquery, xml

From an ajax call I get a response that look like something like this

```
<root>
    <node>
      <innerNode>value</innerNode>
   </node>
```

when I get the response I keep the `<node>` node in a variable,I modify it and I try to insert it back to the xml document using the appendTo method.But appendTo overwrites any existing nodes with the new node. Am I doing something wrong?

the jquery code looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: urlKat,
    async:false,
    success: function(d, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        variableXML = $.parseXML(jqXHR.responseText);

        testXML=$(variableXMLXML).find("innerNode").filter(":contains(value)").parent();
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});

testXML.find("innerNode").text(newValue);
variableXML.find("root).each(function(){
    $(testXML).appendTo($(this));
});
```

Comment: Post the jQuery code in question or you can't be helped :)

Comment: sorry about that.code is now posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part

```
testXML.find("innerNode").text(newValue);
variableXML.find("root).each(function(){
$(testXML).appendTo($(this));
```

of your code and ajax code will be run at the same time.
cause ajax call takes few seconds to connect with server.

you should put that part inside success:

---

*EDIT*: over few hours of work, I finally realized that testXML is not duplicated data but indicates <node> object by reference. It means, jQuery appendTo doesn't override existing node. It is changed when you run this line -

```
testXML.find("innernode").text('newValue');
```

I was confused too, but it became easy when I try to think it HTML-wisely. 
anyway, you should duplicate the node before you make any change.
 
try this way:

```
testXML = $(variableXML)
              .find("innernode")
              .filter(":contains(value)")
              .parent()
              .clone(); //duplicate node before change value
```

and change the value,

```
testXML.find("innernode").text('newValue');
```

and finally attach it 
notice that you don't need to use 'each' to iterate.
jQuery will automatically find all <root> elements and attach new element to them.

```
$(testXML).appendTo($(variableXML).find("root"));
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: thank you for you answer.But I can see that I have the xml response and I see that testXML variable takes a value,could this happens because of ajax call connectivity?I will try it though... :)

Comment: then i dont think it is due to connection thing. what did you try to get and what did you actually get?

Comment: after I call appendTo I want to get something like this <root><node><innernode>value</innernode></node><node><innernode>newValue</innernode></node></root> and instead I get <root><node><innernode>newValue</innernode></node></root>

Comment: @kafrlust Finally i got it. I edited article. try to do this way :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!I'm trying it at the moment and although I haven't managed to make it work I'm still working on it

Comment: @kafrlust i'm so glad to hear that :)